# .net maui application not allowing users to choose files on MacCatalyst

Tags: c#, .net, maui

I am writing a .net maui application that allows users to choose a file from their directory, display the file path for the chosen file, and then open the chosen file. The issue is that on MacCatalyst (I am working on a mac) when the file directory opens for the user to choose a file, all the files are greyed out and unable to be picked. Here is the method for when the PickFileButton is clicked:

```
private async void PickFileButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                //var result = await FilePicker.PickAsync();
                var result = await FilePicker.PickAsync(new PickOptions
                {
                    FileTypes = new FilePickerFileType(
                        new Dictionary<DevicePlatform, IEnumerable<string>>
                        {
                            { DevicePlatform.iOS, new[] { "public.item" } },
                            { DevicePlatform.Android, new[] { "*/*" } },
                            { DevicePlatform.WinUI, new[] { "*/*" } },
                            { DevicePlatform.MacCatalyst, new[] { "*/*" } }
                        })
                });

                if (result != null)
                {
                    filePath = result.FullPath;
                    await FilePathLabel.Dispatcher.DispatchAsync(() =>
                    {
                        FilePathLabel.Text = filePath;
                    });

                }
                
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Handle exception if file picker operation fails
                Console.WriteLine($"File picking failed: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }
```

I have already set LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace and Application supports iTunes sharing to true in Info.plist in case that was what was causing the issue. When I comment out the DevicePlatform.MacCatalyst line, it also doesn't work.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/storage/file-picker?tabs=macios#platform-differences

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been having the same issue. The FilePicker for MacCatalyst is buggy and doesn't work as expected. If I don't specify filetypes and simply try

```
var result = await FilePicker.PickAsync();
```

then files are selectable; however, due to the FilePicker bugs the file isn't always selected. This issue should be fixed in .NET 8. I hope the same fix comes to .NET 7 as well as other bug fixes so we can use the FilePicker on Mac.

This isn't the same issue you've been having, but here's some helpful information to get an idea of what's going on with the NET MAUI FilePicker.

https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/11088

https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/15126